# hard page refresh using highcharts

Tags: caching, highcharts, refresh

I am using highcharts to display the chart. When I select one item from dropdown list it is showing data in the chart.

For example, the first item (arrayList) has 500 data points, second item(arrayList) has 1000 data points, and third item(arrayList) has 1500 data points. When I select first item it is showing 500 data points in the chart. When I select second item it is showing 1000 data points in the chart. But when I select first item after selecting second item the chart showing 1000 data points (the first arrayList is getting the second arrayList size).

If I do the hard refrsh on page, ten it is showing exact data that I want. But I dont know how can I code for hard refresh of a page in highchart. Any suggestion?

Comment: Show some code. How are you setting the data for the chart?

Comment: How do you set data? do you use setData / update / addSeries function? Could you recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have used highcharts for generating the chart. The code is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tn6Kw/4/

Comment: Could you update your example with correct data, because this example doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tn6Kw/7/ 

In my case I used chartData array (coming from DB) and pass this chartData to highchart data. In the example it is not possible to use the exact same code that I used in my application. Cause it involves to setup many things.

Comment: I got the solution. :-) We need to make the array empty after each run.
chartData.length = 0;